# Calling layoutIfNeeded in animations block freezes UI on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

Has anyone experienced the same issue, when calling layoutIfNeeded in animations block freezes UI?

I have a method:

```
- (void)hide {
dispatch_block_t onMain = ^{
    CGFloat height = -viewContent.frame.size.height;

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.15f delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.f relativeDuration:0.7f animations:^{
            self.constraintViewContentBottom.constant = height/3;
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.7f relativeDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            self.constraintViewContentBottom.constant = height;
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
            self.viewBackground.alpha = 0.0f;
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             self.hidden = YES;
                         }];
    }];
};
if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    onMain();
}
else {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), onMain);
}
}
```

Which works perfectly on the many devices, but on the one iPhone 7, the line: `[self layoutIfNeeded];` freezes UI.

I'm not able to debug that device, but can get some logs from it.

Does anyone know how we can solve the problem?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints' constants **before** the animation block. `layoutIfNeeded` is the only thing that has to be put into the block...

Comment: Well, basically if we call it from [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{}]; method - you're right. But I've tried different variants - before, inner - result the same. =(

Comment: And you have to use `dispatch_sync`?

Comment: Don't use dispatch_sync!

Comment: Use dispatch_async instead

Comment: Well, guys, it never calls =) By default it calls from main thread :)

Comment: @Andrei So it also freezes when using `dispatch_async`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta Yes, it does =(

Comment: For other people who land here, I had a similar problem and calling my animation routines using `DispatchQueue.main.async` solved my issue.